# javascript alert showing code insted of string

Tags: javascript

first and foremost i'm new to javascript and coding. second, i'm coding a book store project with javascript with an alert message that shows each customer's total factor. but the alert message shows the code of my function "printFactor" insted of the string that is made by this function. this is my code:

```
   function Book(name, writer, date, price) 
   {
     this.name = name;
     this.writer = writer;
     this.date = date;
     this.price = price;
   }

   function Customer(name, gender, turn)
   {
     this.name = name;
     this.gender = gender;
     this.turn = turn;
     this.numberOfBooks = 0;
     this.totalSum = 0;
     this.bookList = [new Book("-", "-", "-", 0)];


      //Functions.
      this.addBook = function (newBook) {
      this.numberOfBooks++;
      this.bookList.push(newBook);
      };

      this.printFactor = function () {
         var message = "";

         if (this.numberOfBooks === 0) {
             message = "No Books Has Been Added to Book List!";
             return (message);
         }

         else {
             message = this.name + "    " + this.gender + "    Number of Books: " + this.numberOfBooks + "    Customer's Turn: " + this.turn + "\nBooks:\n";

             var i;
             var newMessage;
             for (i = bookList.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                 newMessage = bookList[i].name + "    " + bookList[i].writer + "    " +  bookList[i].date + "    " + bookList[i].price.toString() +"\n" ;
              message += newMessage;
                 this.totalSum += bookList[i].price;
                 this.bookList.pop();
            }

              newMessage = "Total Sum: " + this.totalSum;
              message += newMessage;

              return (message);
    }
};
}

  var book = new Book("Faramarz Bio", "Faramarz Falsafi Nejad", "1377/04/29",  13000);

  var faramarz = new Customer("faramarz", "Male", 3);

  faramarz.addBook(book);
  faramarz.addBook(book);
  faramarz.addBook(book);
  faramarz.addBook(book);


  var m = faramarz.printFactor;


  window.alert(m);
```

Comment: `faramarz.printFactor` is a function. You probably want to call it: `faramarz.printFactor()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the function:

```
var m = faramarz.printFactor();
```

Answer (score 1):

As is your variable `m` contains a reference to the function, but you need to call it to get the result.

```
var m = faramarz.printFactor();

window.alert(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply don't call your function, this should work.
`var m = faramarz.printFactor()`

Beside you reference an unexisting variable 'booklist', that should be "this.booklist"

```
for (i = this.bookList.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
     newMessage = this.bookList[i].name + "    " + this.bookList[i].writer + "    " +  this.bookList[i].date + "    " + this.bookList[i].price.toString() +"\n" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call the function by adding `()` to the end, like this:

```
var m = faramarz.printFactor()
```